# Find global maximum and minimum with EVT

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, extreme-value-theorem

Find the global maximum and minimum with EVT of the function $x^2$ on the (0;8] interval. I know that the maximum would be 64 and it does not have minimum just by knowing the function, but let’s say its a function that I can’t really know it’s graph... am i able to use the EVT since it’s not exactly a closed interval?

Comment: you can always use the limit as x go to the extreme of interval from the right  or left (0+ in this case). and in a closed interval, a function always have a maximum and a minimum

Comment: So if i know the limit of the extreme of the interval I can use EVT anyways?

Comment: yes!! always work on continuous functions.

Comment: But what about an open interval (not half open)? Would it work that way too?

Comment: you just need the lim, you  can say that an open interval $(a,b)$ is a closed interval like $\lim_{\delta \longrightarrow 0^+}[a+\delta, b-\delta]$ and apply EVT on this "closed interval" as delta is never $0$, the interval never goes to $[a,b]$ but always close, as an open iterval.

Comment: i think that is the way to think. but i don´t know a 
rigorous proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I got it now